# Sandboxing website best practices?

Tags: php, svn, sandbox

I currently work in a web shop with almost no formal processes and a million PHP websites, including tricky stuff like custom CMS and shopping cart code.

We are trying to improve things.  I am pushing for CVS/SVN.

My question is, what is the best practice for sandboxing website work?  We are on the LAMP stack.  Some of our sites have hardcoded (or user-inputted links) to the current domain, so setting up a different domain like preview.mysite.com will break links pointing to www.mysite.com.  If we start applying regression tests, perhaps the domains should be uniform for testing?  That can always be done with a local host entry.

So, considering we have lots of sites, it would be nice to have one process for always doing previewing in a proper sandbox.  Wondering how this would integrate with an SVN/CVS cycle.

I am just looking for industry best practices because we are trying to get there.  If that means cloning a site to an extra server, so be it.

Answer (score 1):

So yes, you should have a second STAGE server. What I do is put my code into CVS on my dev box, and do regular commits as i go along. When I am ready to push a version to the "STAGE" server, I go through the files I want to STAGE and tag them STAGE:

cvs tag -F STAGE

Then I go to the STAGE server and do an update with the STAGE flag to get the STAGE version of files:

cvs up -r STAGE

This also sets the sticky tag to be "STAGE" on those files, so in the future, I can just leave the STAGE tag off when I do updates on my stage server:

cvs up

finally, when I've tested my code on the STAGE server, I roll it to the production server using rsync...

We have several developers working together so keeping a stable STAGE version up can get tricky. In that case, if I just have small changes to one or two files, I will just scp them individually over to the production server..

Finally, to ensure I know what is out on my production servers, after I send a file or files  off to the production server, I tag all the files on my stage server as RELEASE, and also as RELEASE20090713  or whatever the current date is.. That way I have moving snapshots though time that I can get if needed. Note though, this doesn't update the sticky tag, so my regular old

cvs up

on the stage server still gets me the latest STAGE files.

Now in your case, as far as the hardcoded URL's goes... You already know.. bad bad bad... so fix them as you go... But you may be able to use apache URL rewriting to rewrite URL's on STAGE to talk to a custom TCP port.

If you have a smart network device like a cisco router, you can set it up to do PAT (port address translation) for your IP's. Port 80 can forward to your regular production webserver, and port 8080 can forward to your STAGE server (its port 80).. Then all you do is have apache do URL rewriting on your STAGE server and append 8080 to all the hostnames it sees. Now all your posts and links will go to the correct STAGE servers, and your apache configs can be exactly the same also.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the hard coded (or user-inputted) domain names: you could add the domains to your [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file). That should solve your problems during development and preview. Your browser will retrieve the IP for www.mysite.com and find 127.0.0.1 or the IP of the preview site in the hosts file. The tricky part is that just by looking at the URL in the browser, you cannot determine whether you are looking at the production site or not. (The [ShowIP addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/590) for Firefox can help you here.)

Regarding CVS/SVN: I would *really* advice you to go for SVN. It's not harder to use than CSV but has some advantages (e.g. renaming is possible). For more information see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-svn-over-cvs).

As for the previewing in a sandbox, this is what we do: we do most of our development on [trunk](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch05s04.html#svn-ch-5-sect-6.1) (or on a branch, but the rest of the process is almost the same). Once we are ready to show it to the customer, we create a [tag](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch04s06.html). This tag is used to update the preview server. If the customer isn't satisfied, we develop some more on trunk (or the branch), create a new tag, update preview with the tag, etc. Once the customer is happy we use the exact same tag running on preview to also update the production server. This way we can be sure that the preview and production server have the same code base.