# Can I checkout a CVS repo on my local machine?

Tags: cvs

Crunch: Can I checkout a repo that is on a drive mapped on my local machine, without having a server running on that directory?

Fluff: I am new at using CVS. I am working on an old project, where all of the original developers are either not with us anymore or have forgotten how they worked on it. After much tribulation, I finally found where the source code for the project is (on a communal drive that I have mapped on my local filesystem), but it is a CVS repo. How can I check this code out, so that I can actually work on it?

I am using a Windows 7 system.

Comment: The Best think you do is change CVS for Git.

Comment: I'd love to, but first I need to get the code!

Comment: CVS has several ways to specify the repository (via `-d ...`, or `$CVSROOT`, or via the `CVS/Repository` file in the current directory). It can be either a local directory or a remote server.

Comment: @RogerRussel: "*The Best think you do is change CVS for Git.*" -- Maybe. CVS still does have *some* advantages. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7871646/827263

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually this is as simple as:

```
cvs -d /path/to/repo checkout .
```

I have assumed use of a *nix system, and this also "just works" if one is using an *MSYS* environment on a Windows system.  The primary difference under *MSYS* is understanding how drive letters are represented.  The following example assumes the repository is on the *C:* drive.

```
cvs -d /c/path/to/repo checkout .
```

The principle also follows if one elects to use *cygwin* instead of *MSYS*, but *cygwin* uses a different method of referencing drive letters:

```
cvs -d /cygdrive/c/path/to/repo checkout .
```

Note that if one is unfamiliar with Windows GNU environments like *MSYS* or *cygwin*, it may be pertinent to note that *MSYS* is a "minimalist" GNU environment implementation and *cygwin* is decidedly not "minimalist".  This could mean that *MSYS* may present less of a challenge to a new adopter - the "minimalist" aspect of *MSYS* will have no negative impact relative to using it for its CVS client.

A potential complication with using CVS clients on Windows is that most tend to change the line termination format of checked out text files to match the format generally used in the client environment.  By way of explanation, if source files were originally checked in with *LF* delimiters, many, or most, CVS clients running under Windows will check out the files with *CRLF* line-termination.  While this can work fine, it can also create issues in the event that the compiler or build environment is sensitive to line termination.  The respondent has experienced numerous situations where such translation did more harm than good.

Unlike many or most other CVS clients, the *MSYS* `cvs` implementation DOES NOT translate line termination of text files on checkout.  If a file in the repository has *LF* line-terminators, the checked out copy has *LF* line-terminators, and if the repository copy is *CRLF* terminated, the checkout out copy will be too.  (Though, one may use `dos2unix` and/or `unix2dos` utilities to change the format of the checked out files.)

Caveat:  The respondent has an *MSYS* bias and uses *MSYS* routinely in an engineering environment; when additional functionality provided by *Cygwin* is needed, the respondent prefers use of a *nix system over a Windows system.

Comment: I'm using windows 7, I just added that to my question. Is there a difference for this command?

Comment: Specifying use of Windows 7 is not really providing enough information for a Windows environment.  There are many CVS clients for Windows.  That said, the command given works just fine if one is using an MSYS environment on Windows, and should demonstrate what needs to be done for any client, and especially for any that support command-line use.